# Are there any side-effects to using `arg` as an argument name in Lua?

Tags: parameters, lua, arguments, special-variables

I was using `arg` as an argument name for a function:

```
function foo(cmd, arg)
    -- etc.
end
```

I just learned `arg` is a special, hidden variable that represents a table of  arguments when using *variable arguments*:

```
function foo(bar, baz, ...)
    -- `arg` now holds arguments 3 and up
end
```

Should I expect any issues with using `arg` as an argument name in my code?

Comment: https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/issues/931

Comment: That's a pretty solid and non-obvious answer... would you add it as an answer?

Comment: I really not sure is it bug or feature. LuaJIT as I know does not have such effect. But since Lua 5.1 does not supports any more it is feature now :)

Comment: @moteus - Thanks for sharing this Lua feature.  LUA_COMPAT_VARARG (turned on by default) is very dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, please note that I am using Lua 5.3 and this is the version I prefer. (Though, I imagine I prefer it simply because it is the one I started on and am most familiar with.)

Secondly, what version of Lua are you using? In Lua 5.3, `arg` refers to the table containing all the command-line arguments passed to a script. For instance, say I had a script called `test.lua` that looked something like this:

```
for i, v in ipairs(arg)  do
    print(i, v)
end
```

If I executed the script as `lua test.lua hello there, friend`, it would produce the output

```
hello
there,
friend
```

Note that in Lua 5.3, `arg` is a member of the global environment table, `_ENV`; thus `arg` is equivalent to `_ENV.arg` or `_ENV["arg"]`.

In Lua 5.3, it seems that `arg` as a marker of variadic arguments in a function has been depreciated. A simple, table-based solution exists though, as in the following example:

```
function foo(...)
    -- Collect the variable arguments in a table.
    local args = {...}
    for i, v in ipairs(args) do print(i, v) end
    return
end
```

The line `local args = {...}` has the same behavior of the variable `arg` within functions in older version of Lua.

Comment: Glad you put this here. There doesn't appear to be any documentation on `{...}`. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I knew that it would cause problems but wasn't sure of what it was in specific. So I decided to try it myself.

I tried the function displayed on your example, and got a stack overflow error.

And according to the official lua website,

> When this function is called, all its arguments are collected in a single table, which the function accesses as a hidden parameter named arg.

So I think it is best to stay away from calling your parameters "arg"